# jquery animate size images - right images not out of screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm resizing images with jquery animate function. The problem i have that the reszing effect is from left to right and when the image is to close to the right side of the screen, the image is being cut.

Any suggestions?

I tried to play with top and right but couldn't figure it out until now.

```
function resizeImages()
{
    $.fn.random = function() {
        return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length));
    }
    image= $(".Collage img").random();
    var positions = image.position();
    image.css('z-index',1000);
    image.css('position',"fixed");
    image.random().animate({height:"400px",width:"400px" },3000);
    image.random().animate({height:imageWidth,width:imageWidth},{ duration: 4000,  complete:function(){

        image.css('z-index',1);
        image.css('position',"relative");
        GetImages();

    }});

}
```

default size of the images is 
Thanks

Comment: Please add your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: can you edit your post with your code please?

Comment: as per you question it looks like the parent has the `overflow:hidden` property which hides any element which moves out of it

Comment: Anyone knows how it can bedone?